# log4j logger filtering by package name is ignored for OWASP ESAPI

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I currently have log4j configured with an XML configuration file that has two appenders, "file" and "email".  Both of these are working properly, but I would like to not send an email for errors generated internally by ESAPI, so I put a new logger into the XML file.  The complete list of loggers is:

```
<logger name="com.companyname" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
    <appender-ref ref="email" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false">
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
    <appender-ref ref="email" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
    <appender-ref ref="email" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.owasp" additivity="false">
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</logger>

<root>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
    <appender-ref ref="email" />
</root>
```

However, this doesn't work.  I still receive emails for errors generated within ESAPI (specifically, the org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLogger class).

I have also tried using "org.owasp.esapi", "org.owasp.esapi.reference", "org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLogger", and even "org", but all of those fail to work in exactly the same manner.

The only thing I can do to make it stop sending mail for the ESAPI errors is to remove the "email" appender-ref from the root logger, which I don't want to do.  Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, ESAPI was using an entirely different scheme for producing its category names than the rest of the application.  After furiously debuggering the ESAPI and Log4J code, I determined that the errors being produced by ESAPI had a category of "IntrusionException", so the correct logger would be:

```
<logger name="org.owasp" additivity="false">
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</logger>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how this code is different from the code in your question.

Comment: You're right, I pasted the wrong thing.  I will check it again when I get to work tomorrow and see what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that ESAPI adds to the class package the name that you put in the property Logger.ApplicationName of the esapi.properties plus ":". For example in my case, if I have a class mypackage.MyClass ESAPI prints: ExampleApplication:mypackage.MyClass - [EVENT SUCCESS Anonymous:null@unknown ....

I need to put in my log4j.xml

```
<logger name="ExampleApplication:mypackage.MyClass" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</logger>
```

I don't Know if it could be the same problem because your problem it's not in a owner class, by I hope this can help you.